# Reopen request for CEO salary question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Is a high CEO salary in large corporations justified?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/143321/is-a-high-ceo-salary-in-large-corporations-justified/143328#143328)

Lots of factual and logical reasons exist. Shouldn't be closed for 'Opinion'

Comment: What I don't understand is why it got so many downvotes? It's not *that* badly written... perhaps some CEO's took it personally? I also think there is a valid question and opportunity for OP to learn (or to change their mindset). Will try to edit it to improve it's appearance.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I think it's really more a philosophical/societal question. It's likely to dredge up strong opinions regarding pay inequality, the history of labor, etc, etc.  It's pretty clearly not a question about navigating the work place and doesn't seem at all suited for this forum.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere the reasons behind pay scales are pretty important. It's not an ideal question, but I've seen worse.

Comment: "Is their pay justified?" -- how is that not primarily opinion-based?  A question about the factors that inform CEO pay would be workable, but this'll need some editing to get there, in my opinion.

Comment: @Kilisi - I've seen worse as well. I don't think that makes the question at hand any better though. It's an interesting question, but not for The Workplace IMHO.